# Latex system of equation to Wolframalpha

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

I have latex string of a system equation:

```
\\left\\{ \\begin{array} { l } { y = - \\frac { 5} { x } } \\\\ { y = - 5} \\end{array} \\right.
```

but i don't know how to input or convert it into wolframalpha. Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Your LaTeX string is incomplete or badly formatted.  Alpha will interpret legitimate LaTeX.

Examples below in Mathematica and Alpha.

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you take an example of system of equation? i try my latex with mathjax and it render correctly http://imgur.com/QsQ46K9